# Squealing sound

Tags: sound, fax

I have a xiaomi air 13, and it came with windows 10 I installed ubuntu 14.04Lts along the side,  when I turned it on in windows it has a squeling sound like a fax not too loud but is there,  when I turn it on in ubuntu it's there but not as loud and it goes away fast, what could this be ?
I'm afraid it could be the HDD 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Ubuntu does not make a squealing sound. We don't do hardware support here, so we're probably not going to be much help.

Comment: I understand that here is  not hardware support but is a bit of a puzzle and I'm sure that there must be a person out there that can think why this is happening, I am a new user I just bought the computer and installed linux